# How to synch the writing on a file from multiple thread

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

Hey there i have the following problem: i have some kind of "Registration" function that writes on a file that is called from insied a thread so that the program behaves like this:

```
                        main()
                         |
        ----------------------------------------
        |                 |                    |                  
       *thread 1       *thread2             *thread3
        |                 |                    |
      Register           Register            Register  
        |                 |                    |
        ----------------------------------------
                          |
                       sameFile
```

**Now the problem is:** Can i use a mutex *inside the register function*'s critical part (check if the user is already written on the file and then write on the file)  even if the register function is not a thread itself but it is called by a thread?
Or should i use the mutex in the thread, before calling Register function?

Comment: You can use a mutex wherever you want. Functions are not threads. And you can't not have a thread.

Comment: If it's called from a thread it's running on a thread.  A *thread* isn't a function, and a function isn't a thread.  It's a kind of higher-level execution primitive.  If you need to call functions in a thread and protect critical sections of those functions with a mutex you can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a mutex anywhere it makes sense to.

*No* function **is** a thread, they're all just functions - one of which is the first one called when the thread starts. Although that is probably called by an internal library function, so isn't really any more special than any other function it calls later.

Using a mutex inside a function (that you expect to be called from multiple threads) to protect a shared resource is exactly the normal use-case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'm new to this concept of thread actually..
Also, if you have some good resources about thread i would be pleased to read them!